# For this code that reads if its a palindrome or not, I want to replace [::-1] with a for loop and get the same function

Tags: python

```
string = (input("Input your own string: "))
string = string.lower()
if string == string[::-1]:
  print("This is a Palindrome")
else:
  print("This is not a Palindrome")
```

I want to replace [::-1] with a for loop and get the same function

Comment: In order to do what?

Comment: Which part of the code?

Comment: How would a for loop make this more efficient?

Comment: Are you saying you think looping through each character and comparing them one at a time would be faster than what you have now?

Comment: yes random davis

Comment: I am pretty sure, that a for loop would be much slower than this solution

Comment: If your string were 1000s of characters long, then yes, there are faster ways to test for a palindrome.  But for normal-length strings, I suspect this is going to be faster than anything you hand code.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly don't know what you really mean or what your goal is but you can do something like

```
for i in range(amount):
    string = (input("Input your own string: "))
    string = string.lower()
    if string == string[::-1]:
        print("This is a Palindrome")
    else:
        print("This is not a Palindrome")
```

or

```
run = True
while run == True:
    string = (input("Input your own string: "))
    string = string.lower()
    if string == string[::-1]:
        print("This is a Palindrome")
    else:
        print("This is not a Palindrome")
```

Comment: While this is the most sensible approach given the original question of OP, this does not seem to be what he wants, looking at his edit

Comment: @user8408080 Oh I see. Thank you for letting me know!

Comment: Sorry I meant to say how you do I replace [::-1] with a for loop

Answer (score 1):

The following function is checking any text for a palindrome using a loop.

```py
def check_palindrome(text):
    text = text.lower()
    text_length = len(text)
    for i in range(int(text_length/2)):
        if text[i] != text[-i-1]:
            print("This is not a Palindrome")
            return
    print("This is a Palindrome")

string = (input("Input your own string: "))
check_palindrome(string)
```

Comment: Sorry I meant to say how you do I replace [::-1] with a for loop

Comment: Is this faster than OPs approach?

Comment: To be honest I expect that OPs solution runs faster, because it provides a more Pythonic solution.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by using a for loop to make it more efficient? Do you want it to ask for string again and again? If so then try while loop

```
While True:
  string = (input("Input your own string: "))
  string = string.lower()
  if string == string[::-1]:
    print("This is a Palindrome")
  else:
    print("This is not a Palindrome")
```

Comment: Sorry I meant to say how you do I replace [::-1] with a for loop

Comment: Oh then you can use mpSchrader's answer